# Only observing sign of the output of a linear model under Gaussian assumption

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, estimation, linear-model, regression-coefficients

Suppose the linear model is $y = \beta x + \epsilon$, where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1), \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, s^2)$. If we only observe the sign of the output $y_i$, and the number of observations is large, $i$ how can we estimate $\beta$?

Comment: via probit regression :)

Comment: @JohnMadden Care to expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probit regression operates under the assumption that there is some latent linear model that has Gaussian errors, but we only see the signs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) This is exactly the situation described in the question, so probit regression sounds like the way to go.

A simulation shows this to be pretty slick and to give estimated coefficients that are close to the OLS coefficients and close to the true values.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10000
x <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
b0 <- -1
b1 <- 1
y <- b0 +b1*x + rnorm(N)

# Set indicator for positivity of y
#
z <- y > 0

# Fit a linear model to the original x and y
#
L <- lm(y ~ x)

# Fit a probit model to x and the indicator for the sign of y
#
P <- glm(z ~ x, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

summary(L)$coef[, 1]
summary(P)$coef[, 1]
```

```
> summary(L)$coef[, 1]
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.9939896   1.0080528 
> summary(P)$coef[, 1]
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.9853826   0.9783042
```

**EDIT**

Worth a mention is that the standard errors on the probit model are higher. Since there is less information available to the probit model (the `z <- y > 0` line is lossy compression of the `y` variable), I suspect that this is not just a fluke. Consequently, if you have the original `y`, it seems that you can get tighter coefficient estimates by using the linear model, even though you can do something reasonable if you only have the lossy-compressed `z <- y>0`.

Comment: @AdamO It seems pretty spot-on if I set `b0 <- 0` and use `0 + x` in the regression calls to force the intercepts to be zero. Perhaps you can post an answer clarifying what happens when the intercept is omitted (though I do suspect this just to be sloppy notation in the original question).

Comment: ah right I made a mistake editing the code and kept the intercept as non-zero.

Comment: @AdamO Do you mean that you just made a coding error when you modified my code in your own R sessions? I was hoping to learn about some theoretical concern about intercept-free probit models.

Comment: Yes, well the interesting bit is that you say probit is for when we only observe the sign (+/-) when, in fact, the response can be any threshold $z = y > \theta$ and the $\beta$ is still estimable but only when the intercept term is included. The interpretation of the intercept becomes a complicated mix of $\theta$ and the actual shift $a$ of the untransformed response $y = a + b x + e$.

Comment: @AdamO You mean if there is a nonzero intercept but we do not model it in the probit regression?